# Retrofit response object is not displayed in recyclerview

Tags: android, retrofit, android-viewmodel

I have some json data I am getting from the web for which I am using retrofit to retrieve in my repository and send it to my viewmodel to be displayed in an activity. The response is all success and I verified my POJO matches the json. When I create hard coded Team object and send it from the repository response to my viewmodel I get the data displayed in the UI but not from the response. Here is my repository.

```
private TeamRepo() {
        teamMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Team> getTeam(final String team){
        RetrofitServiceApi retrofitServiceApi = RetrofitService.getRetrofitInstance()
                .create(RetrofitServiceApi.class);
        Call<Team> teamCall = retrofitServiceApi.getTeam(team);
        teamCall.enqueue(new Callback<Team>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Team> call, Response<Team> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", response.toString());
                    teamMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());

                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.e("response body", response.message());
                    }
                    //teamMutableLiveData.setValue(team);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Team> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error response", t.toString());
                //TODO
            }
        });

        return teamMutableLiveData;
    }
```

My api looks like the following.

```
@GET("api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php")
    Call<Team> getTeam(@Query("t") String team);
```

and the service is

```
private static Retrofit retrofit;

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/";

public static synchronized Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

> https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=Arsenal

Partial json data looks like the following

```
{
  "teams": [
    {
      "idTeam": "133604",
      "idSoccerXML": "9",
      "idAPIfootball": "42",
      "intLoved": "2",
      "strTeam": "Arsenal",
      "strTeamShort": "Ars",
      "strAlternate": "Gunners, Arsenal Football Club, AFC",
      "intFormedYear": "1892",
     }
   ]
}
```

Team POJO is as follows

```
public class Team {
    @SerializedName("idTeam")
    private String idTeam;
    @SerializedName("idSoccerXML")
    private String idSoccerXML;
    @SerializedName("idAPIfootball")
    private String idAPIfootball;
    @SerializedName("intLoved")
    private String intLoved;
    @SerializedName("strTeam")
    private String strTeam;
    @SerializedName("strTeamShort")
    private String strTeamShort;
    @SerializedName("strAlternate")
    private String strAlternate;
    @SerializedName("intFormedYear")
    private String intFormedYear;

public String getIdTeam() {
        return idTeam;
    }

    public void setIdTeam(String idTeam) {
        this.idTeam = idTeam;
    }

    public String getIdSoccerXML() {
        return idSoccerXML;
    }

    public void setIdSoccerXML(String idSoccerXML) {
        this.idSoccerXML = idSoccerXML;
    }

    public String getIdAPIfootball() {
        return idAPIfootball;
    }

    public void setIdAPIfootball(String idAPIfootball) {
        this.idAPIfootball = idAPIfootball;
    }

    public String getIntLoved() {
        return intLoved;
    }

    public void setIntLoved(String intLoved) {
        this.intLoved = intLoved;
    }

    public String getStrTeam() {
        return strTeam;
    }

    public void setStrTeam(String strTeam) {
        this.strTeam = strTeam;
    }

    public String getStrTeamShort() {
        return strTeamShort;
    }

    public void setStrTeamShort(String strTeamShort) {
        this.strTeamShort = strTeamShort;
    }

    public String getStrAlternate() {
        return strAlternate;
    }

    public void setStrAlternate(String strAlternate) {
        this.strAlternate = strAlternate;
    }

    public String getIntFormedYear() {
        return intFormedYear;
    }

    public void setIntFormedYear(String intFormedYear) {
        this.intFormedYear = intFormedYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Team` mapping class?

Comment: @Fabio plz see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server response is a JSON object that contains a "teams" array. You need to create a `SearchResult` object:

```
public class SearchResult {
    @SerializedName("teams")
    private List<Team> teams;

    public List<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }
}
```

And then replace your call to Retrofit to return a `SearchResult` object:

```
@GET("api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php")
Call<SearchResult> getTeam(@Query("t") String team);
```

You'll get the results in

```
response.body().getTeams(); // Don't forget to check for nulls
```

Comment: How so? I am searching by team so, I should get one team not teams. Correct?

Comment: This is what I get if I do what you suggested in my repository class. IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: You are searching by teams, but the API returns a `List<Team>` wrapped in an object, let's say, `SearchResult`. That's why it says it expects an object and not an array